# Pass data from spring boot controller(redirect) to angular page without passing query params?

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot

Is there a way to pass data from spring boot controller to angular page?
I am doing redirect and passing query params. It works but there is limit on number of characters in URL.

Is there any other way?

```
@PostMapping(value = "/aalcomplaint/api/complaint/lodge-complaint")
  public ModelAndView lodgeComplaint(final HttpServletRequest request, ModelAndView modelAndView, final RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
    //Map<String, String[]> paramMap = request.getParameterMap();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("policyNumber=").append(request.getParameter("policyNumber"));
    sb.append("&firstName=").append(request.getParameter("firstName"));
    sb.append("&lastName=").append(request.getParameter("lastName"));

    modelAndView.setViewName("redirect:/#/list-complains?&" + sb);
    return modelAndView;
  }
```

Comment: Nope! This should be other way round. The AngularJS app should request the required data from back-end, instead of back-end sending the required data to the client app.

Comment: Is it really **ANGULARJS** ??

Comment: 31piy, yes I know but my retirements are such that I receive form post in my controller and need to show data in front end in a form. We do not use any database to store such info